RL model not learning when using Stable Baselines 3 and custom gymnasium environment
I am trying to use reinforcement learning to solve a scheduling problem. The goal is to run a generator whenever the electricity prices are the highest, but there is limited amount of fuel. The price of electricity is known for each upcoming hour.
When trying to train a model on this I don't seem to get any improvements over random actions. I feel like my problem could be related to how I define the observation space. I built it from these values:
Current state - motor on or off (basically is the same thing as the action - run the generator or not from the previous action. I added it so later I set a starting state as well as add some penalty for changing state).
Current hour - gets incremented by one each step, not sure if this is needed.
Fuel left - how much fuel is left, is decremented by one each step/hour the engine is run.
Price list - list of prices for each hour - this does not change during an episode.
The reward is returned after each step by returning the price of the current hour if the motor is run and 0 if it is not.
class Engine(gym.Env):
    # Reward for when motor is run for more than the allowed hours
    OUT_OF_BOUNDS_REWARD = -1000.0

    def __init__(self, price_list=None, allowed_h_to_run=8,
                 render_mode="console"):
        super(OneEngine, self).__init__()
        if price_list is None:
            price_list = [-10, -10, -10, -10, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0]
        # 2 actions - do not run generator for current hour, run generator for current hour
        n_actions = 2
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(n_actions)
        # The observation is:
        # Current state - motor on or off
        # Current hour - current hour in the list of prices
        # Hours left to run on  - how many hours(steps) is the motor allowed to run
        # Price list
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
            low=np.array([self.CurrentState.OFF.value, 0, 0] + [smallest_price] * self.price_list_len),
            high=np.array([self.CurrentState.ON.value, self.price_list_len + 1, allowed_h_to_run + 1] +
                          [largest_price] * self.price_list_len),
            shape=(3 + self.price_list_len,),
            dtype=np.float32)

    def step(self, action):
        if action == self.CurrentState.ON.value:
            self.allowed_h_to_run -= 1
            self.current_state = self.CurrentState.ON
        elif action == self.CurrentState.OFF.value:
            self.current_state = self.CurrentState.OFF
        info = {}
        terminated = False
        # Reward depending on if engine was on
        reward = float(self.price_list[self.current_hour] * action)
        if self.allowed_h_to_run < 0:
            # Too many hours used , not allowed
            reward = self.OUT_OF_BOUNDS_REWARD
            terminated = True
        # Increment current hour
        self.current_hour += 1
        if self.current_hour >= self.price_list_len:
            # we reached end of price list
            terminated = True
        truncated = False  # do not limit the number of steps
        observation = np.concatenate((np.array([self.current_state.value]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array([self.current_hour]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array([self.allowed_h_to_run]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array(self.price_list).astype(np.float32)))
        return (
            observation,
            reward,
            terminated,
            truncated,
            info,
        )

After training this I don't seem to get any improvements on how the model performs. Even though I am not changing the price list - the end goal would be to create a random price list for each episode. I have tried different algorithms PPO, A2C, RecurrentPPO without improvements. I also played with the learning_rate and ent_coef without success.
This is what I see in tensorbaod.

full code:
def test():
    price_list = [-10, -10, -10, -10, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0]
    env = OneEngine(allowed_h_to_run=6, price_list=price_list)
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = RecurrentPPO("MlpLstmPolicy",
                         env,
                         verbose=1,
                         tensorboard_log="./a2c_test_tensorboard/")
    model.learn(episodes)

class OneEngine(gym.Env):
    """
    Custom Environment that follows gym interface.
    One engine that can be on or off
    List of prices
    Nr of hours allowed to run
    """
    # Render in console
    metadata = {"render_modes": ["console"]}
    # Reward for when motor is run for more than the allowed hours
    OUT_OF_BOUNDS_REWARD = -1000.0
    # Define constants for clearer code
    class CurrentState(Enum):
        OFF = 0
        ON = 1

    def __init__(self, price_list=None, allowed_h_to_run=8,
                 render_mode="console"):
        super(OneEngine, self).__init__()
        if price_list is None:
            price_list = [10, 80, 30, 20, 140, 152, 188, 30, 50, 130]
        self.render_mode = render_mode
        # Save initial state for reset
        self.initial_hours_to_run = allowed_h_to_run
        self.price_list = price_list.copy()
        # Position in price list
        self.current_hour = 0
        self.price_list_len = len(price_list)
        smallest_price = min(price_list)
        largest_price = max(price_list)
        # How much hours of gas does the engine have
        self.allowed_h_to_run = allowed_h_to_run
        self.current_state = self.CurrentState.OFF
        # 2 actions - engine OFF, engine ON
        n_actions = 2
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(n_actions)
        # The observation is:
        # Current state - motor on or off
        # Current hour
        # Hours left to run on  - how many hours(steps is the motor allowed to run)
        # Price list
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
            low=np.array([self.CurrentState.OFF.value, 0, 0] + [smallest_price] * self.price_list_len),
            high=np.array([self.CurrentState.ON.value, self.price_list_len + 1, allowed_h_to_run + 1] +
                          [largest_price] * self.price_list_len),
            shape=(3 + self.price_list_len,),
            dtype=np.float32)

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        """
        :return: (np.array)
        """
        super().reset(seed=seed, options=options)
        # Initialize the agent with off state, initial hours to run and initial price list
        self.current_state = self.CurrentState.OFF
        self.allowed_h_to_run = self.initial_hours_to_run
        self.current_hour = 0
        initial_observation = np.concatenate((np.array([self.current_state.value]).astype(np.float32),
                                              np.array([self.current_hour]).astype(np.float32),
                                              np.array([self.initial_hours_to_run]).astype(np.float32),
                                              np.array(self.price_list).astype(np.float32)))
        return initial_observation, {}

    def step(self, action):
        if action == self.CurrentState.ON.value:
            self.allowed_h_to_run -= 1
            self.current_state = self.CurrentState.ON
        elif action == self.CurrentState.OFF.value:
            self.current_state = self.CurrentState.OFF
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Received invalid action={action} which is not part of the action space"
            )
        info = {}
        terminated = False
        # Reward depending on if engine was on
        reward = float(self.price_list[self.current_hour] * action)
        if self.allowed_h_to_run < 0:
            # Too many hours used , not allowed
            reward = self.OUT_OF_BOUNDS_REWARD
            terminated = True
        # Increment current hour
        self.current_hour += 1
        if self.current_hour >= self.price_list_len:
            # we reached end of price list
            terminated = True
        truncated = False  # we do not limit the number of steps here

        observation = np.concatenate((np.array([self.current_state.value]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array([self.current_hour]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array([self.allowed_h_to_run]).astype(np.float32),
                                      np.array(self.price_list).astype(np.float32)))
        return (
            observation,
            reward,
            terminated,
            truncated,
            info,
        )

    def render(self):
        if self.render_mode == "console":
            if self.current_hour > 0:
                print(f"Hour nr.: {self.current_hour} \tPrice:{self.price_list[self.current_hour - 1]}\t\t\t{self.CurrentState(self.current_state).name}")
                print(f"Hours allowed to run {self.allowed_h_to_run}")
            else:
                # TODO:
                print("Initial state...")
            if self.allowed_h_to_run < 0:
                print(f"Attempted to use more hours than allowed. Penalty: {self.OUT_OF_BOUNDS_REWARD}")

    def close(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()

I am a beginner at RL, any advice on how to approach this will be greatly appreciated.
